# How do I upload a project to my portfolio website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, portfolio

This is probably really simple but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to upload/connect a personal project to my portfolio website. I've uploaded my project files to the GitHub repository that contains. I want to connect my portfolio project to the "log cabin" section on my website.

GitHub repository: https://github.com/pinksharpie/pinksharpie.github.io
Site: kourtneykodes.com

Here's a screenshot of my finished project. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4RDx.png)

I want to connect my finished project to my portfolio website. If possible, I'd like to showcase my project on my portfolio site AND have a live link to view the project on GitHub.

Comment: I guess you want to add links to your readme file. It is in markdown (md) format. You can get more info at https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/ and you can use something like https://stackedit.io/app# as an editor. This page https://github.com/mundimark/awesome-markdown-editors lists some more markdown editors.

Comment: There is multiple ways to do this. Can you specify the framwork or language you are working with?

Comment: You have already created a GitHub page for your [portfolio](https://kourtneykodes.com/#portfolio).  See the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages) on how to add more pages to showcase projects.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to get this done. You can use an embedded window (iframe) CHECK IT OUT or you can create a card on your website with a picture, details of your projects an anchor tag () leading to the project's site.